# CDF can't opencv mathematica scripts ***.key

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, cdf

I got a mathematic script   xxx.key    
  but when i opened it with CDF reader.CDF reader shows tip "This notebook was created in a more recent version of Mathematica and is not compatible with this version of Mathematica. Contact Wolfram Research (www.wolfram.com) for upgrade information."  
 But I have the newest version of CDF reader. what's the problem?